# Show $z^4 + e^z = 0$ has a solution in $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq 2\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Show $z^4 + e^z = 0$ has a solution in $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|  \leq 2\}$.

I would like if in the proof the tools of algebraic topology were preferred over the other tools of analysis, complex analysis, algebra etc.

Comment: Yes, Rouché is the standard method for these problems. The proof is somewhat topological, though.

Comment: @julien, shouldn't it be *four* roots?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, of course. That's what I said. Seriously, I forgot it was $z^4$ and took it for $z$ when I concluded...Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tools are the same. Let $f(z)=z^4+e^z$ and let $g(z)=z^4$. Show that $\dfrac{f}{|f|}$ and $\dfrac{g}{|g|}$ are homotopic as maps $\{z: |z|=2\} \to S^1$. Note that if $h\colon S^1\to S^1$ has nonzero degree, then $h$ has a root in $D^2$. (Why?)

Comment: But this is just re-proving Rouché's theorem...

Comment: Yes, @Potato, whether complex analysis or differential topology or algebraic topology, it's all the same idea :) P.S. The argument principle is just a generalization of the intermediate value theorem, and differential topology puts it all in the most general context.

Comment: Is there a way to see your last claim (nonzero degree implies the existence of a zero) topologically, without using the argument principle?

Comment: @Potato, yes, if no zeroes on the disk, then the map extends to the disk, so that gives a homotopy between the map and the constant map. (Think of the disk as a cylinder with the top circle identified to a point.)

Comment: Nice! I've seen similar arguments before, but they always seem a bit tricky to me. Do you know of a good reference for topological techniques in complex analysis? Some searching brought up a book by Beardon, but it's out of print.

Comment: Hmm, not truly, I picked more of this up from differential topology, to be honest. But Narasimhan's and Krantz's books (http://www.amazon.com/Complex-Analysis-Variable-Raghavan-Narasimhan/dp/0817641645/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1369694488&sr=8-1&keywords=narasimhan and http://www.amazon.com/Complex-Analysis-Geometric-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0883850354/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1369694544&sr=1-2&keywords=krantz+complex) play up the interplay with topology and differential geometry (the latter in a serious way).

Comment: @TedShifrin I do not think I get your argument. How do you use the fact that the disk radius is 2? We could define a disk of a radius $\epsilon$ and there does not seem anything to fail in your argument. Of course, for a sufficiently small $\epsilon$ the equation does not have the solution.

Comment: Right, David. Note that you have to make sure the homotopy between $f$ and $g$ cannot pass through $0$ (because we're projecting onto $S^1$), so you actually have to pay attention to $|f|$ and $|g|$ on the boundary circle!