# Zeroes of $z^4+e^z$ in the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

How many zeroes does $f(z)=z^4+e^z$ have in the **unit** disc?

ADDED: can you calculate them?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/404238) the same question is asked about the disk of radius $2$. It can be solved easily by Rouché's theorem since when $|z|=2$, if $z=x+iy$ then $|e^z|=e^x\leq e^2$ so
$$|f(z)-z^4|=|e^z|\leq e^2\leq 9<16=|z^4|$$ therefore there are $4$ roots in that disc (up to multiplicity).

Now when $|z|=1$ we don't have this inequality, nor can we use the same trick by subtracting $e^z$ instead, since when $|z|=1$, $1/e\leq |e^z|\leq e$, one side is less than $1$ and the other greater.

This **can** be used to show that there are no roots in the right half of the disc, where by going around a curve approximating the boundary of the right half of the disc, so always $x>0$,  we get $e^x>1\geq |z|$. A direct calculation also shows no roots are on the $y$ axis.

Any ideas on how to deal with the left half?

Comment: if $z$ is a root such that $|z|<1$ then $|z^5-z^4-1|\leq 1$. Maybe this helps...

Comment: Maybe use cauchys argument principle.

Comment: "therefore there are 4 roots in that disc (up to multiplicity).". Correct. Now solve the equation $f(z)=0$ (using $W$) and verify that none of the (infinitely many) roots lie on the unit circle.

Comment: you need to show that $2 \pi (n-1) < |\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{4 z^3 + e^z}{z^4+e^z} dz| < 2 \pi (n+1)$

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM How do you propose to use this fact?

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis I don't understand your suggestion. What is $W$? My problem is to solve $f(z)=0$...

Comment: @user1952009 Well I don't really know how to deal with this integral, it seems even more problematic.

Comment: @UrBen-Ari-Tishler see my edit to JeanMarie's answer

Comment: @user1952009 but how did you plot it? using some approximation or by some calculation? As I said, I don't know how to calculate this integral. I understand why this would give me the answer (by the argument principle) but I need a way to estimae it "manually".

Comment: @UrBen-Ari-Tishler all you need is a bound on $\frac{f'(e^{it})}{f(e^{it})}$, then you can sample $\log f(e^{it})$ and 'unwrap' its imaginary part as I did. Here it is obvious that sampling $t$ every $0.01$ is enough, so it proves there are $2$ zeros (with multiplicity) inside the unit disk

Comment: @user1952009 what do you mean by "unwrapping"? How do you obtain a bound? As I said, I need a manual proof, so sampling 600 times is no good.

Comment: @UrBen-Ari-Tishler you need to read a course on the argument principle, and the [phase unwrapping](https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=phase%20unwrapping) means making $arg f(e^{it})$ continuous when drawing it for $t \in [0,2\pi)$

Comment: @UrBen-Ari-Tishler "Phase unwrapping" is a classical term in signal processing for "keeping memory of the number of turns one has made around a point", instead of restarting at $0$ every time one has reached $2 \pi$...

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a solution**, just a graphical representation of the modulus $|f(z)|$ (with colors tending to red when values tend to zero). This shows that there are two roots inside the unit disk with conjugate (approximate) values $-0.67003127469869344 \ \pm 0.5161249765067623 i$ (the two others are outside the unit disk).
[image]

Another way to be convinced graphically of the fact that there are 2 zeros inside the unit circle is by plotting $\frac{\text{arg }f(e^{it})}{2 \pi}$ (unwrapped) (using the [argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle)) .

[image]

Comment: @ UrBen-Ari-Tishler Thanks for having provided the second graphic which is another way of "seeing" the situation.

Comment: It wasn't me who added the second plot

Comment: So, I have lost the trace of the unknown contributor who is welcome to say "it's me". I always appreciate co-operation.

Comment: @JeanMarie my graphic is a proof, together with a bound on $\frac{f'(e^{it})}{f(e^{it})}$ and the fact I used 600 sample points

Comment: Is a graphic a proof, I don't think so... It is no more a proof than my own graphics.

Comment: @JeanMarie it is because you don't know the argument principle so well, all we need is to show the closest integer to the unwrapped $arg$ is $2$

Comment: @user1952009 I don't want to polemicate. But one thing is to "see" something and be 100% convinced that this is true, another thing is to prove it by clean analysis tools (majorations etc...). I would like to have the opinion of other people on this issue.

Comment: @JeanMarie you are boring... I told you what you need to make it rigorous : a bound for $f'/f$ on the unit circle, as I said here it is obvious it works (I didn't compute an explicit bound for $f'/f$ because I know looking at my graphic it will work, but yes you need to compute it and it will be rigorous)

Comment: @user1952009 All right, I am boring. You have just pointed out in your  parenthesis what is missing...

Comment: @JeanMarie I told it before